# C inserting a number at a specific location of an integer

Tags: c

What I'm attempting to do is create a hamming code starting point from a integer that is storing a binary number.
so for 1100111 I want to insert 0's so the int looks like 11000110100-inserting 0's at  1-2-4-8. I'm super new to C and in Java I would probably just use char.At() to accomplish that but haven't found an efficient way to do this in C, I was wondering if there was an easier way to accomplish this rather than inserting into an array, I didn;t find the bit operators of any help, Thanks.

```
  int convToHamVal(int binNumOne, int binNumTwo, int  *hamOne, int *hamTwo){
    //Function to do so, binNumOne/Two contain binary numbers of ASCII chars
    (length 7)

  array[0] = 0;
  array[1] = 0;
  array[2]
  array[3]
  array[4] = 0;
  array[5]
  array[6]
  array[7]
  array[8] = 0;
  array[9]
  array[10]


    return 1;
    }
```

Comment: Is this your "inefficient way" or is there some code you forgot to include?

Comment: @Jongware im asking if there is a char.At equivalent for C.

Comment: the only way i could think of splitting up the binary int would be to modulo divide but i run into error when a 0 is a leading number

Comment: Have you looked at the bit field notation?

Comment: This is very confusing for me.
1100111 is 103 decimal, correct?
11000110100 is 1588 decimal?   Is that what you want to do?  If yes, C bit fields are the way to go and  if you do not want to twiddle bits.

Comment: @jim McNamara I'm trying to get it set up in a hamming code notation where I will later change the zero's depending on the parity.

Answer (score 0):

What i ended  doing was using the array route, since ASCII is 7 bits I created an array of size 11 and just used the divide method to convert from dec to binary and modded to get the number and stored in array. Then i just rearranged the array to get the hamming format of 000_000_0_ _.

I researched bit field notation and found that very useful and more efficient but was cut for time so i took the route I understood, thanks.

```
int convertToBinaryOne(int binarrOne[], char ascLetters[],int *binNumOne){
/*convert from char to int*/
int decNumOne = ascLetters[0];

/*convert from dec to BINARY*/


int i, binary = 0;

    for(i = 6; decNumOne != 0; i--) {

        binary = decNumOne%2;   
        decNumOne = decNumOne/2;
        binarrOne[i] = binary;
    }
```